# How to link a word of one markdown file to another markdown file in doxygen?

Tags: hyperlink, markdown, doxygen

I have a main markdown file in one folder and other markdown files in subfolders and i wanted to link the word of main markdown file with the markdown files of subfolders. How Doxygen automatically link words with the files of the same project? If automatically is not possible then how to do this?

Comment: As far as I know markdown has no possibilities to link words. Also doxygen has direct possibility to link "normal" words, it can only link things like functions / classes / namespaces etc. Furthermore doxygen has the possibilities of `\anchor`  and in combination with teh `\ref` command you can accomplish linking of words (it is a tedious process and based on the scarce information from your question).